# check for closest greatest element in list a for every element of list b any optimization suggestion to this code for huge lists

Tags: python, list, algorithm, optimization

**Function:**
Check for closest greatest element in **'list a'** for every element of **'list b'**

if element found, remove that element from original list

so the next element can be compared

> list a=[2,3,4], list b=[0,0,7] =>2,3,-1

if no element found, return: -1

and finally prints the count of -1

any suggestions to optimize this code for huge lists

```
import sys
def next(arr, target): #method returns index of nex greater element or -1
    start = 0
    end = len(arr) - 1
    ans = -1
    while (start <= end):
        mid = (start + end) // 2
        if (arr[mid] <= target):
            start = mid + 1
        else:
            ans = mid
            end = mid - 1
    return ans
def main():

        q=list(map(int,sys.stdin.readline().split())) #list1
        r=list(map(int,sys.stdin.readline().split())) #list2
        q.sort()
        r.sort()
        var,count=0,0
        for tst in r:
                var=next(q,tst)
                q.pop(var)
                if var == -1:
                    count+=1

        print(count)
main()
```

Comment: You should use a data-structure that supports efficient search and removal of elements, like a red-black tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sort two list first. then compare two values. if a[i] is not grater than b[i] then go next element of a.

```
a = [2,3,4]
b = [0,0,7]

a.sort()
b.sort()
c = [];
x = 0;
for i in range(len(b)):
    while x < len(a):
        if a[x] > b[i]:
            c.append(a[x])
            break;
        x = x + 1;
    if x >= len(a):
        c.append(-1)
    else:
        x = x + 1;
for i in c:
    print(i)
```